# One word substitution

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

What would be the one word substitute for a property or a behavior displayed by a product which it is not primarily designed for but such a behavior exists due to the property of the material it is manufactured with.

For example: An electrical transformer has hysteresis loss due to the property of the material it is made up of but this is not something it is designed for.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: If there is such a term it's likely a pretty esoteric engineering jargon.  What you are talking about is an *intrinsic* property of the material -- which isn't an answer, but might help you when searching for one.

Comment: Would *substrate* work?

Comment: @LawrenceC I am afraid that it is not the word I am looking for although 'intrinsic' as pointed out by Andrew seems to be partially correct in my case but it can more specifically be used for material and not the manufactured product.

Comment: @A.Sinha  try the electrical engineering SE? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions  As I said, if if the term exists it's likely to be jargon and only known/used by a select few.

Comment: @Andrew i think the electronic context was given just as an example, i think this is not only about electronics but products as a whole. Anything that is made of something would fit as an example.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but i think he means like if you get a doll or something similar made of rubber it will have elastic properties and it wont have conductivity, Those were inherited from the doll's material but not the primary purpose of the doll as a product.

Comment: It must be a word that works with inheritance, intrinsic as @Andrew said is a good one.

Comment: @Zorkind you are right, transformer is just an example, it could be any product.

Comment: So you want a word that represents the "side effects" of using a certain material to construct the product.

Comment: many words could be used to describe it, but not sure if they can be THE word. "collateral" or "by-product" are also viable words.

Comment: Basically I want to find a word for the unintentionally induced biased behavior to the sensors due to the intrinsic properties of the material they are manufactured with.

Comment: the result of the innate characteristics of the sensors?

Comment: Oh i think "Adverse effect" or "adverse results" works

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that a single-word substitution, if an appropriate word exists, may be very specialized. If this is a request for the word in a specific context or usage example, more details on that specific example may be helpful.

However, I think that some more standard words may help, especially if you loosen the one-word criterion. I'll submit **[incidental](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/incidental?s=t)**, as describing something which is true of the product but unrelated to its intended function:

> An electrical transformer has hysteresis loss due to incidental properties of its components/component materials.